# Pthread create function

Tags: multithreading, function, pthreads

I am having difficulty understanding the creation of a pthread.

This is the function I declared in the beginning of my code

```
void *mini(void *numbers);   //Thread calls this function
```

Initialization of thread

```
pthread_t minThread;

pthread_create(&minThread, NULL, (void *) mini, NULL);



void *mini(void *numbers)
{
    min = (numbers[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ( numbers[i] < min )
        {
            min = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

numbers is an array of integers

```
int numbers[8];
```

Im not sure if I created the pthread correctly. 
In the function, mini, I get the following error about setting min (declared as an int) equal to numbers[0]:

```
Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'
```

My objective is to compute the minimum value in numbers[ ] (min) in this thread and use that value later to pass it to another thread to display it. Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor improprieties in this pgm but it illustrates basically what you want to do.  You should play around, break and improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *mini(void *numbs)
{
    int *numbers = (int *) numbs;

    int *min = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *min = (numbers[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (numbers[i] < *min )
            *min = numbers[i];

    pthread_exit(min);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t minThread;

    int *min;

    int numbers[8] = {28, 47, 36, 45, 14, 23, 32, 16};

    pthread_create(&minThread, NULL, (void *) mini, (void *) numbers);

    pthread_join(minThread, (void *) &min);

    printf("min: %d\n", *min);

    free(min);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass 'numbers' as the last argument to pthread_create().  The new thread can then call 'mini' on its own stack with 'numbers' as the argument.

In 'mini', you shoudl cast the void* back to an integer array in order to dereference it correctly - you cannot dereference a void* directly - it does not point to anything:)

Also, it's very confusing to have multiple vars in different threads with the name 'numbers'.

Comment: Can you please clarify about casting the void* back to an integer array? Are you referring to the function call? Also, what parameter would I pass mini since numbers would be my argument now.